# WL.JSONStore is undefined error in IBM mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am getting WL.JSONStore is undefined error in mobile browser simulator while I am trying to use JSONStore in my mobile application.I am using IBM mobilefirst (version 8.0.0-2017091111). [image]

```
function wlCommonInit(){

WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options).then(function () {
     alert("intialized successfully");

    }).fail(function (errorObject) {
        alert("failed to initialize collection\n"+ JSON.stringify(errorObject));
    });   

document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click", onSubmit, false);

}

function onSubmit(){
var collectionName="people";
var data={firstName:$('#first').val(),middleName:$('#middle').val(),lastName:$('#last').val()};
WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data, options).then(function () {
   alert("added data successfully");
}).fail(function (error) {

});
}
```

Comment: This can happen if the project is missing JSONStore plugin or if the JSONStore initialization has not been complete. Can you try the sample here:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/

and see if you get the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Add cordova jsonstore plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore
```

See more: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/#adding-jsonstore

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore

Comment: I have followed the above link but it is not working in the Android Platform It is Showing That WL.JsonStore is not Intialzed

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify which version of 'cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore' your app is  using (run command 'cordova plugin ls').

Did you follow this tutorial 
[Link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/#adding-jsonstore)